# create multivalued index

Tags: java, solr

How do we create multivalued index through code.

Comment: How do we answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Define a field as multi-valued:

In your schema.xml, for the fields you want to have multiple values, add the "multiValued" attribute:

```
   <field name="features" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

More information can be found: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options